# AppleScript Not Having Permission to Save Files

Tags: permissions, applescript

When using Applescript to write a file to my external hardrive, it shows the following error:
`The document “Untitled 2” could not be exported as “test.txt”. You don’t have permission.`
My code is supposed to write a file using TextEdit, and save it as an `.txt` file. My code:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
make new document
set theDate to current date
set text of document 1 to do shell script "curl 'www.google.com'"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    if menu item "Make Plain Text" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Format" of menu bar 1 exists then
        keystroke "t" using {shift down, command down}
        keystroke return
    end if
end tell
save document 1 in "HARDRIVE:test.txt"
end tell
```

(HARDRIVE is my external hard drive).
Why is it causing this error? What can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a file object as path --> **file** "some HFS path"

```
save document 1 in file "HARDRIVE:test.txt"
```